# Mimicking the fetch of a web page with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

Running JMeter 5.3 on MacOS/Linux. I am trying to mimic the fetch of a web page. The page's HTML has references to 3 static assets (2 JS files and 1 CSS file). The CSS has references to 3 static assets (2 font files & 1 image).

The test plan is fairly simple. It has a Transaction Controller (SML Home Page) which in turn has a HTTP Request Sampler (Fetch SML HTML & Embedded Assets) and an If Controller (Conditional Fetch). The If Controller has a Blazemeter Parallel Controller or Sampler (Fetch CSS Assets). The image below shows both as being enabled but either one is fine (because they all should fetch the same 3 assets in parallel).

[image]

I have the following questions

- Not all parameters mentioned in [JMeter HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) are showing up on the Basic or Advanced tab of the HTTP Request Sampler. Is there another way to set these?
- In the logs I see `o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser`. And from the documentation for `CssParser` I see that `CSS Parser used to extract from CSS files external urls`. Should the CssParser be used by JMeter to fetch the dependencies - i.e. the image & font files? If this works then the test plan could be simplified further.
- Because CSS referenced assets weren't automatically pulled, I used a Blazemeter Parallel Controller to fetch those assets after the main sample (HTML) and the sub samples (2 JS files and 1 CSS file) are fetched with a 200 Status. I am noticing fair amount of connection issues (mentioned below) when running Blazemeter (v0.9) Parallel Connector. I have tried both the Parallel Controller and Parallel Sampler. Sampler has fewer connection issues than the Controller.

  - Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
    Response message:Non HTTP response message: Socket closed
  - Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    Response message:Non HTTP response message: Connection pool shut down
  - Response code:Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException
    Response message:Non HTTP response message: Data received in non-data state: 6
  - Response code:Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RequestAbortedException
    Response message:Non HTTP response message: Request execution failed
  - Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.io.InterruptedIOException
    Response message:Non HTTP response message: Connection already shutdown

Answer (score 0):

You should not be downloading the CSS files and images manually, it should be sufficient to tick `Retrieve All Embedded Resources` and `Parallel Downloads. Number` boxes at the "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults))

[image]

This way you will get browser-like behaviour and will be able to use [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to simulate browser cache.

More information [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses)